# Eggs in a convection microwave

Tags: eggs, microwave, convection

I'm trying to cook eggs in a convection microwave. It is NOT using microwave to do it - I've made bread, pies, etc in it. Any recommendations on timing and temps?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are going to use your convection microwave *without the [microwave function](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64457/why-is-putting-an-egg-in-the-microwave-not-recommended)*, your question boils down to **"How do I boil or bake an egg in a (toaster) oven?"**.

The answer? Slowly.
In an oven, heat transfer is via air, which is a way worse conductor than water. So you put your eggs either directly on the grill rack or in a small container. Many sources recommend a metal muffin tray, because all the hot eggs han be handeled at once and in the rare case of breakage, the mess is contained. Temperature recommendations vary a bit, but for hard boiled eggs, the rule of thumb is:

> 30 minutes at 160-180 C / 320-355 F

A word of warning:
**Do not bake your eggs too long!**
If the temperature of the egg exceeds the boiling temperature, the water in the egg turns into steam and you have created a little egg-bomb, which may go off inside your oven or while you are handling the hot egg. The effect is better known from failed attempts at boiling eggs in a microwave, but the danger is real.

Comment: What about... immersing the egg in some water? That will at least keep you from superheating the egg....